# Inserting spaces In between operand and operators, getting String out of Bounds

Tags: java, whitespace, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I have an assignment to create a program that converts Infix expressions to Postfix. I needed to insert spaces in between operand and operators, I keep getting StringIndexOutOfBounds for some reason. Here's my java code for the process.

```
public class Processor {
public String addSpace(String str){
    String finalstr = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))){
            int x = i;
            String temp = "";
            do{
                temp+=str.charAt(x);
                x++;
            }while(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(x)));
            finalstr+=(temp+" ");
            System.out.println(temp+" added to final");
            i=(x-1);
            System.out.println(x+" is x and i is "+i);
        }
        else if(isOperator(str.charAt(i))){
            finalstr+=(str.charAt(i)+" ");
        }
    }
    return finalstr;
}

public boolean isOperator(char a){
    switch(a){
        case '+':
        case '-':
        case '/':
        case '*':
        case '(':
        case ')':
        return true;
        default: return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this loop

```
do {
    temp += str.charAt(x);
    x++;
} while (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(x)));
```

You increase `x` and you take the character at position `x` without checking if that character exists. At the end of string if the character is a digit you go over the length of the string

Comment: OH! Thank you so much dear sir. How stupid of me. I really can't work properly with a toothache going on. Thank you again!

Comment: If you that this solution is a good one for your question you can upvote it and flag it with the green check as correct answer. Thank you